# PHP - Changing Phone Number Format with Regex

Tags: php, regex, replace

I'm trying to figure out how to convert a phone number in the format
+18761234567
into
876-123-4567
using a replace Regex.

Comment: This could be done without regex (just using [strstr()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) if the format is always xxx-xxx-xxxx

Comment: @andyb if you benchmark the `preg_replace()` against calling `substr()` three times you'll find `preg_replace()` is faster

Comment: @James C I'm sure it is, however performance wasn't a requirement and the OP might only be doing this once and if so I believe that regex is overkill. I'm not disagreeing that your solution is more elegant and performant though!

Comment: @andyb "regex" was a requirement though ;)

Comment: @James C haha, yes indeed it was - point taken! However I am always mindful of [Regular Expressions: Now You Have Two Problems](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think this should work

```
preg_replace('/^\+1(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/i', '$1-$2-$3', '+18761234567');
```

I'm assuming that the `+1` is constant and then use the `\d` shortcut to match decimal characters. The value in `{}` is the number of characters to match.

Comment: Very good regex, because it won't break numbers outside of the North American numbering system.

Answer (score 1):

Also, there is a Regexp Library on the Internet. It may be of help.

Search for 'phone':

http://www.regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=phone&c=-1&m=-1&ps=20

Comment: Link corrected. Next time remember you can try to find the site and suggest an edit, instead of downvoting ;-).

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not regex but this also works :-)

```
$num = '+18761234567';
$formatted = substr($num, 2, 3).'-'.substr($num, 5, 3).'-'.substr($num, 8);
```

Answer (score -2):

This assumes there are 2 characters a the beginning to ignore.

```
preg_replace("/([0-9a-zA-Z+]{2})([0-9a-zA-Z]{3})([0-9a-zA-Z]{3})([0-9a-zA-Z]{4})/", "$2-$3-$4", '+18761234567');
```

Comment: it's not right to match on a-zA-Z too. You won't find those characters in a phone number!

Comment: Actually it could if it was a vanity number. For example 877-Call-Today